# Entry Point Not Found In sfml-system-2.dll

Tags: c++, sfml

The code itself compiles fine using mingw 4.8. Just the outputted file crashes with the error.

My command line:

```
g++ main.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

I've tried this with multiple computers and I get the same thing.

Comment: Please provide further information.

Comment: What further information is there to tell? It auto crashes with just a popup box that has that text.

Comment: I'd suspect the dll's. Where they compiled with the same compiler? Same settings? Why is it called sfml-system-2.dll ??

Comment: I think that are the linking specs for linux, not windows.

Comment: No mingw for windows works this way and the linker would have complained.. It didn't which makes me suspect that the dll is the wrong one.

Comment: It seems that the most recent version of SFML doesn't work on MinGW 4.8, only with 4.7. Is there a way around this at all? Or do I have to wait for them to update SFML?

Comment: What happens when you compile it? I built 2.1 with MinGW 4.8

Comment: All goes well and there are no errors.

Comment: Are you sure it is not a 32bit / 64 bit compilation issue?

Comment: I'm using 32bit version of both MinGW and SFML so I don't see how that could happen. I added a "-s" to the end of all the sfml g++ aguments and it spat out this http://pastebin.com/PyFkd3Dd

Comment: To compile SFML as a static library you need to reconfigure its CMAKE for static configuration. (easy)
You must use the option -DSFML_STATIC in your own compilation.. no need for -s

Comment: @Lumaio *"It seems that the most recent version of SFML doesn't work on MinGW 4.8, only with 4.7. Is there a way around this at all? Or do I have to wait for them to update SFML?"* Thats not true. I have a project using SFML that worked perfectly with MinGW GCC4.8 on windows 7

Comment: @Manu343726 He most likely meant there are no official binaries for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the error message into the text block itself as well, instead of just having it in the title.

Also you'd be better of simply asking on the SFML forum, instead of asking on the GitHub tracker (confirmed issues only) and here.

If you use MinGW 4.8 then you need to recompile SFML yourself, since SFML doesn't provide official binaries for that compiler. You can find the information on how to build SFML and how to use SFML in the [official tutorials](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/). Read them carefully otherwise you'll miss the important points and get frustrated because it isn't working.

If nothing helps, you can also use my [Nightly Builds](http://www.nightlybuilds.ch/), but these use a compiler of the family MinGW-w64 and GCC version 4.9.